# Mysqli is installed on my system and the extension is enabled in php.ini but I can't find the actual extension

Tags: php5, centos6.4

Centos 6.4 X86_64 with Apache 2.2.4 and PHP 5.4.17. I've rebuilt PHP to include mysqli.
Phpinfo shows mysqli installed.  Php.ini has the extension un-commented. 
How do I get the mysqli.so into the lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non.../ directory? I apologize if I left something out - I'm a Linux noob. I've searched all over for similar issues but none of the fixes seem to work to actually get mysqli.so into the extension directory. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The extension is not working? Try at the linux shell : php -i | grep extension_dir and it will filter out only the lines in php configuration with extension directories. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Recently spent a couple of hours on this one myself. Make sure that you check the path for your extension folder is set correctly. If in doubt place the full path in: -

```
extension_dir = "C:\PHP7\ext"
```

Comment: That doesn't answer where the extension actually is, instead it requires to know the path already. Not to mention that the question was about a Linux system.

Comment: The issue could be due to the path and as the path varies it makes sense I simply use an example. May not be a complete guide to fixing the problem but to be marked down for pointing someone in the right direction? Nice!